# Divide by value for a specific factor given time (dplyr, data.table)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have data in a long format like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  projection1 = c(2,4,3),
  projection2 = c(3,1,4),
  historical_data = c(2,3,4),
  time = c(1,2,3)
) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = val, projection1:historical_data) %>% 
  mutate(key = key %>% factor())
```

The data then looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
   time key               val
  <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1     1 projection1         2
2     2 projection1         4
3     3 projection1         3
4     1 projection2         3
5     2 projection2         1
6     3 projection2         4
7     1 historical_data     2
8     2 historical_data     3
9     3 historical_data     4
```

Now, I would like to calculate the relative difference each year of the value from projection1 and projection2 relative to historical_data. Thus, I would like my data to end up like so:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
   time key               val pct_diff
  <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 projection1         2    1    
2     2 projection1         4    1.33 
3     3 projection1         3    0.75 
4     1 projection2         3    1.5  
5     2 projection2         1    0.333
6     3 projection2         4    1    
7     1 historical_data     2    1    
8     2 historical_data     3    1    
9     3 historical_data     4    1
```

I always end up splitting and merging to get new seemingly redundant columns containing values that already resides in the current `dataframe`/`tibble` to make the calculations.  I was wondering if there is an elegant `dplyr` or perhaps data.table solution to this? Or perhaps you'll be able to direct me to a question where it is already answered. Haven't comes across one myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple way using groups:

```
 data.frame(
  projection1 = c(2,4,3),
  projection2 = c(3,1,4),
  historical_data = c(2,3,4),
  time = c(1,2,3)
) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = val, projection1:historical_data) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(pct_diff = (val  / val[key == "historical_data"]))

# Groups:   time [3]
   time key               val pct_diff
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 projection1         2    1    
2     2 projection1         4    1.33 
3     3 projection1         3    0.75 
4     1 projection2         3    1.5  
5     2 projection2         1    0.333
6     3 projection2         4    1    
7     1 historical_data     2    1    
8     2 historical_data     3    1    
9     3 historical_data     4    1
```

If you insist that the `key` column is a factor than you would have to slightly modify the above code.

Comment: Great, inspired me to the following, where I can keep my factor: `df %>% mutate(key = key %>% 
                factor() %>%
                fct_relevel("historical_data")) %>% 
  arrange(key) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(pct_diff = (val / first(val, order_by = c(key))))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach using `data.table` and using jangorecki comment using `==` instead of the slower `grep`:

```
DT[, ratio := 1][key!="historical_data", 
    ratio := DT[key=="historical_data"][.SD, on=.(time), i.val/x.val]]
```

Or shorter but likely slower:

```
DT[, ratio := DT[key=="historical_data"][.SD, on=.(time), i.val/x.val]]
```

output:

```
   time             key val     ratio
1:    1     projection1   2 1.0000000
2:    2     projection1   4 1.3333333
3:    3     projection1   3 0.7500000
4:    1     projection2   3 1.5000000
5:    2     projection2   1 0.3333333
6:    3     projection2   4 1.0000000
7:    1 historical_data   2 1.0000000
8:    2 historical_data   3 1.0000000
9:    3 historical_data   4 1.0000000
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("time key val
1 projection1         2
2 projection1         4
3 projection1         3
1 projection2         3
2 projection2         1
3 projection2         4
1 historical_data     2
2 historical_data     3
3 historical_data     4")
```

Comment: `grep("historical_data", key)` will not be very efficient, why not `key=="historical_data"` ?